# Detect 'Replacement Character' with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to detect a [replacement character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm) in an input box with javascript or jQuery?

I've tried to just detect the character itself with:

```
if ($("input").contains('�')) {
    alert("detected");
}
```

but doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unless your string literally contains that character, it is far more likely that it contains an *invalid* character that is being *rendered* as the replacement character.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol is it possible to detect an invalid character then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BAfs3/1)**

**HTML**

```
<input name="test">
```

**JQuery**

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('input').on('input',function(){;
        if ($("input").val().indexOf('�')!== -1) {
            alert("detected");
        }
    });
});
```